# XSL returns nothing

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new in writing XSL.
I am trying to extract some data from a XML file using XSLT.

The XML file and the XSL file are here below.

This is my XML file (full not an extract to be sure ;-):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AggregatedBillData xmlns="http://www.atrias.be/migdgo/20150630/Bill/AggregatedBillData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ent="http://www.atrias.be/migdgo/20150630/Entities" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.atrias.be/migdgo/20150630/Bill/AggregatedBillData ../../Messages/Bill/DGO-BI-INT-50-AggregatedBillData.xsd">
<HeaderMessage>
    <ent:MessageId>d83c111c-e655-4481-8022-fb2e0e88dd4a</ent:MessageId>
    <ent:MessageDateTime>2018-07-11T12:00:00+02:00</ent:MessageDateTime>
    <ent:ContextId>011c38c8-71f6-4730-bf44-2ca1f9d2f12e</ent:ContextId>
    <ent:Module>I81</ent:Module>
    <ent:Label>IA2</ent:Label>
    <ent:Sector>23</ent:Sector>
    <ent:SenderId>5414495999995</ent:SenderId>
    <ent:ReceiverId>5414488009809</ent:ReceiverId>
    <ent:MinorVersion>0</ent:MinorVersion>
</HeaderMessage>
<Invoice>
    <Id>0</Id>
    <Sector>23</Sector>
    <BillType>IE6</BillType>
    <BillPurpose>IE5</BillPurpose>
    <RectificationFlag>false</RectificationFlag>
    <CalculationDateTime>2018-01-01T12:00:00+01:00</CalculationDateTime>
    <GridAccessProvider>
        <ent:EanGln>5499780282808</ent:EanGln>
    </GridAccessProvider>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <LineNumber>500004500000001</LineNumber>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Unit>KWH</Unit>
        <ConsumptionMonth>--01</ConsumptionMonth>
        <CreditLineFlag>false</CreditLineFlag>
        <TariffComponent>
            <Code>?</Code>
            <Direction>E17</Direction>
            <CostCategory>D</CostCategory>
            <VatRate>0.21</VatRate>
            <GlobalisationCode>
                <Code>E</Code>
            </GlobalisationCode>
            <Tariff>
                <Code>T220</Code>
            </Tariff>
        </TariffComponent>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <LineNumber>500004500000002</LineNumber>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Unit>KWH</Unit>
        <ConsumptionMonth>--02</ConsumptionMonth>
        <CreditLineFlag>false</CreditLineFlag>
        <TariffComponent>
            <Code>?</Code>
            <Direction>E17</Direction>
            <CostCategory>D</CostCategory>
            <VatRate>0.21</VatRate>
            <GlobalisationCode>
                <Code>E</Code>
            </GlobalisationCode>
            <Tariff>
                <Code>T220</Code>
            </Tariff>
        </TariffComponent>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <LineNumber>500004500000003</LineNumber>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Unit>KWH</Unit>
        <ConsumptionMonth>--03</ConsumptionMonth>
        <CreditLineFlag>false</CreditLineFlag>
        <TariffComponent>
            <Code>?</Code>
            <Direction>E17</Direction>
            <CostCategory>D</CostCategory>
            <VatRate>0.21</VatRate>
            <GlobalisationCode>
                <Code>E</Code>
            </GlobalisationCode>
            <Tariff>
                <Code>T220</Code>
            </Tariff>
        </TariffComponent>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <LineNumber>500004500000004</LineNumber>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Unit>KWH</Unit>
        <ConsumptionMonth>--04</ConsumptionMonth>
        <CreditLineFlag>false</CreditLineFlag>
        <TariffComponent>
            <Code>?</Code>
            <Direction>E17</Direction>
            <CostCategory>D</CostCategory>
            <VatRate>0.21</VatRate>
            <GlobalisationCode>
                <Code>E</Code>
            </GlobalisationCode>
            <Tariff>
                <Code>T220</Code>
            </Tariff>
        </TariffComponent>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <LineNumber>500004500000005</LineNumber>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Unit>KWH</Unit>
        <ConsumptionMonth>--05</ConsumptionMonth>
        <CreditLineFlag>false</CreditLineFlag>
        <TariffComponent>
            <Code>?</Code>
            <Direction>E17</Direction>
            <CostCategory>D</CostCategory>
            <VatRate>0.21</VatRate>
            <GlobalisationCode>
                <Code>E</Code>
            </GlobalisationCode>
            <Tariff>
                <Code>T220</Code>
            </Tariff>
        </TariffComponent>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <LineNumber>500004500000006</LineNumber>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Unit>KWH</Unit>
        <ConsumptionMonth>--06</ConsumptionMonth>
        <CreditLineFlag>false</CreditLineFlag>
        <TariffComponent>
            <Code>?</Code>
            <Direction>E17</Direction>
            <CostCategory>D</CostCategory>
            <VatRate>0.21</VatRate>
            <GlobalisationCode>
                <Code>E</Code>
            </GlobalisationCode>
            <Tariff>
                <Code>T220</Code>
            </Tariff>
        </TariffComponent>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <LineNumber>500004500000007</LineNumber>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Unit>KWH</Unit>
        <ConsumptionMonth>--07</ConsumptionMonth>
        <CreditLineFlag>false</CreditLineFlag>
        <TariffComponent>
            <Code>?</Code>
            <Direction>E17</Direction>
            <CostCategory>D</CostCategory>
            <VatRate>0.21</VatRate>
            <GlobalisationCode>
                <Code>E</Code>
            </GlobalisationCode>
            <Tariff>
                <Code>T220</Code>
            </Tariff>
        </TariffComponent>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <LineNumber>500004500000008</LineNumber>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Unit>KWH</Unit>
        <ConsumptionMonth>--08</ConsumptionMonth>
        <CreditLineFlag>false</CreditLineFlag>
        <TariffComponent>
            <Code>?</Code>
            <Direction>E17</Direction>
            <CostCategory>D</CostCategory>
            <VatRate>0.21</VatRate>
            <GlobalisationCode>
                <Code>E</Code>
            </GlobalisationCode>
            <Tariff>
                <Code>T220</Code>
            </Tariff>
        </TariffComponent>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <LineNumber>500004500000009</LineNumber>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Unit>KWH</Unit>
        <ConsumptionMonth>--09</ConsumptionMonth>
        <CreditLineFlag>false</CreditLineFlag>
        <TariffComponent>
            <Code>?</Code>
            <Direction>E17</Direction>
            <CostCategory>D</CostCategory>
            <VatRate>0.21</VatRate>
            <GlobalisationCode>
                <Code>E</Code>
            </GlobalisationCode>
            <Tariff>
                <Code>T220</Code>
            </Tariff>
        </TariffComponent>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <LineNumber>500004500000010</LineNumber>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Unit>KWH</Unit>
        <ConsumptionMonth>--10</ConsumptionMonth>
        <CreditLineFlag>false</CreditLineFlag>
        <TariffComponent>
            <Code>?</Code>
            <Direction>E17</Direction>
            <CostCategory>D</CostCategory>
            <VatRate>0.21</VatRate>
            <GlobalisationCode>
                <Code>E</Code>
            </GlobalisationCode>
            <Tariff>
                <Code>T220</Code>
            </Tariff>
        </TariffComponent>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <LineNumber>500004500000011</LineNumber>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Unit>KWH</Unit>
        <ConsumptionMonth>--11</ConsumptionMonth>
        <CreditLineFlag>false</CreditLineFlag>
        <TariffComponent>
            <Code>?</Code>
            <Direction>E17</Direction>
            <CostCategory>D</CostCategory>
            <VatRate>0.21</VatRate>
            <GlobalisationCode>
                <Code>E</Code>
            </GlobalisationCode>
            <Tariff>
                <Code>T220</Code>
            </Tariff>
        </TariffComponent>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
        <LineNumber>500004500000012</LineNumber>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Unit>KWH</Unit>
        <ConsumptionMonth>--12</ConsumptionMonth>
        <CreditLineFlag>false</CreditLineFlag>
        <TariffComponent>
            <Code>?</Code>
            <Direction>E17</Direction>
            <CostCategory>D</CostCategory>
            <VatRate>0.21</VatRate>
            <GlobalisationCode>
                <Code>E</Code>
            </GlobalisationCode>
            <Tariff>
                <Code>T220</Code>
            </Tariff>
        </TariffComponent>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <MarketParty>
        <ent:EanGln>0000000000000</ent:EanGln>
    </MarketParty>  
    <BillArea>
        <Id>4444</Id>
        <Sector>23</Sector>
    </BillArea>
</Invoice>
<AggregationRun>
    <ent:Id>1</ent:Id>
    <ent:NumberOfAggregations>12</ent:NumberOfAggregations>
    <ent:TotalAmount>1200</ent:TotalAmount>
    <ent:Aggregation>
        <ent:Id>1</ent:Id>
        <ent:TotalAmount>100</ent:TotalAmount>
    </ent:Aggregation>
</AggregationRun>
```

I am trying to display the LineNumber and Amount for each InvoiceLine with the following XSLT:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" mlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Aggregated Bill</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>LineNumber</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="AggregatedBillData/Invoice/InvoiceLine">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="LineNumber"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSLT returns nothing.

What is the problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Nicolas

Comment: Your XML sample is invalid - are you missing the closing `AggregatedBillData` tag?

Comment: Also, your XSLT input is invalid, according to Saxon. Line 2 should read `xmlns:xsl=..` not `mlns:xsl=..`. Your XSLT processor should have told you so; if it did not, use another one. Please make sure your samples don't contain **trivial** errors such as these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a default namespace declared in your source XML:
`xmlns="http://www.atrias.be/migdgo/20150630/Bill/AggregatedBillData"`

You need to add this declaration (including a namespace prefix) to your XSLT and use it in your XPath expressions:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:my="http://www.atrias.be/migdgo/20150630/Bill/AggregatedBillData">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Aggregated Bill</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>LineNumber</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="my:AggregatedBillData/my:Invoice/my:InvoiceLine">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="my:LineNumber"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="my:Amount"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

You must provide some prefix in order to reference elements from that namespace in XPath.

If you look on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5t11tzt(v=vs.110).aspx) it explains a bit about how XPath treats an empty prefix as the **null** namespace:

> XPath treats the empty prefix as the null namespace. In other words, only prefixes mapped to namespaces can be used in XPath queries. This means that if you want to query against a namespace in an XML document, even if it is the default namespace, you need to define a prefix for it.
>   For example, without defining a prefix for the XML document above, the XPath query /books/book would not return any results.
>   A prefix must be bound to prevent ambiguity when querying documents with some nodes not in a namespace, and some in a default namespace.